# How to convert from one mode to the other?

Tags: theory, harmony, modes

I have no idea how modes work atm, I'm pretty competent everywhere else in theory, but I struggle with modes.

Is it at all possible to convert modes? like from minor to phrygian? and what would be the best way to learn the modes?

Comment: "and what would be the best way to learn the modes?" - to listen to a lot of modal music. Then you just reproduce : ))

Comment: What kind of modal music: Medieval, jazz, folk, etc? They don't all work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to look at modes.

Consider that each and every mode has a 'parent' key. Thus each one mentioned here contains all the notes from C major: C Ionian,D Dorian, E Phrygian, F Lydian, G Mixolydian, A Aeolian, B Locrian. Basically imagine the notes C D E F G A B written round a circle, and the modes quoted will centre on the appropriate letter name. Read round the circle for the sequence.

Or - Consider that each mode will have its own personal note spacings. As in Ionian - TTSTTTS, or Dorian - TSTTTST, etc.

For me, harking back to parent key works better, so if I meet C Dorian, I think in terms of the notes from B♭ major.

As far as converting goes, yes it works. Calculate what *number* note each is in the original key/mode, and translate to the same *number* note in the new key/mode. Just don't expect all new transcriptions to sound convincing!